# Publish History in Windows Azure Websites

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, azure

How can i check the Publishing History of Windows Azure Websites. We are publishing our application using Publish Profile in Visual Studio 2012. We are using Code First Approach of Entity Framework

Last night someone changed the DB or Application from Production server but we are unable to check the History...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can check the publish history, if you are using publishsettings file.

But you can use most of the version controls repositories like Git, TFS, Dropbox etc., and integrate automated deployments to azurewebsite from them. In that case deployment history will be maintained by Azure itself and you can view the history on Azure Portal.

[Check out this ref for Git Deployment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577582/DeployingplusanplusAzureplusWebsiteplusfromplusSou)